# Python CGI prints file content in same line of browser

Tags: python, browser, cgi

I have file "ip"

file IP content:

```
1.1.1.1,0.0.0.0

2.2.2.2,0.0.0.0
```

When i try to print the file using python cgi

```
f.open('ip'',r')
dat = f.read()
print (dat)
```

The browser displays it as below, by printing both 1st n 2nd line in one row.

1.1.1.1,0.0.0.0 2.2.2.2,0.0.0.0

Is there a way to print the file in same format, instead printing all content in same line?

Thanks

Comment: isn't it because browser expects HTML? In that case, try `print(dat.replace("\n","<BR>"))`

Comment: I get blank page, nothing printed

Comment: last attempt (I cannot test your case): `print("<HTML>\n<BODY>\n"+dat.replace("\n","<BR>")+"\n</BODY>\n</HTML>")`

Comment: no luck,its still blank

Comment: is there a way to test this? where to gain access to python CGI? a test server somewhere?

Comment: Not sure about the test env, however is did some changes and get below output

Comment: f = open('ip', 'r')
line = f.readlines()
f.close()
print (line)
  
output:
['1.1.1.1,0.0.0.0\n', '2.2.2.2,0.0.0.0\n']

Answer (score 0):

After having below, now o/p format is same as i/p. Thank You!

```
f = open('ip', 'r')
line = f.read().replace('\n', "<br>")
f.close()

print line
```